# Create keyboard shortcut to type special characters missing because of different physical and software language keyboard layout

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, language-support

I have an English QWERTY keyboard, however I want to type in Spanish/Catalan layout. I am having problems with the angle brackets (< and >) because in the Spanish layout there is a specific button for these but not in the English one. So I wanted to create a shortcut so

<kbd>LeftAlt</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> creates <kbd><</kbd> and

<kbd>LeftAlt</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> creates <kbd>></kbd>.

The problem I am having is that when I release <kbd>LeftAlt</kbd> a top bar opens, for example in the browser a top bar with File Edit View History Bookmarks Tools Helps opens, and my custom shortcut doesn't work.

How could I create a functional shortcut for this two symbols using <kbd>LeftAlt</kbd>?

Comment: For me that top bar opens when I **release** <Left Alt>, not when **pressing** it. And it does so only when I press and release <Left Alt> alone without combining it with some other key.

Comment: You are right, my bad. However, my shortcut <LeftAlt> + <z> doesn't work.

Comment: How about showing us exactly what you tried? Personally I would have edited `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/es` and used <Right Alt> instead to access those symbols.